# How do I include VM arguments while exporting a JavaFX program?

Tags: java, javafx

When I export my JavaFX program as a runnable JAR file, I cannot run it because an error appears: "a JNI error has occured, please check your installation and try again". I suppose the problem is related with the warning I get while exporting: "VM arguments will not be part of the runnable JAR. Arguments can be passed on the command line when launching the JAR", but I actually am not sure if this is the reason. I do not want to pass them on the command line, I want a "click to open" solution.

Comment: A runnable jar is not the correct approach in the first place. The problem is you need to provide (via command line arguments) the path to the JavaFX module, which needs to be installed on the end user machine (and its location will vary). You should create an application bundle instead (including the Java+JavaFX runtime). You can do this with a tool such as `jpackage`: see the links under "Packaging" in the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info)

Comment: I just want a simple way to share my programs. I use runnable jars because I can convert them into executable files, and this is my goal. Is this wrong?

Comment: Explain how you are converting the runnable jars into executable files.

Comment: I actually wrap it, using a wrapper software.

Comment: Ok, so use `jpackage` as your “wrapper software”, since that allows you to create a custom JVM with the JavaFX modules included.